# python mock 'from a.b import c'

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using `mock` (Python 2.7) to test that a class method that calls a function defined in a different file. A quick sketch:

```
# c.py
from a.b import foo

class Bar(object):
    ...
    def do_foo(x):
        if condition(x):
            foo(x)
        else:
            do_something_else
```

I'm trying to mock `foo`, but I just can't seem to pin it down--`with patch('c.foo')` doesn't seem to work, nor does `with patch('a.b.foo')`.

I also tried something like

```
# c.py
from a import b

class Bar(object):
...
def do_foo(x):
    ...
    b.foo(x)

# test_c.py
...
    with patch('b.foo')
    ...
```

but that didn't work either.

Comment: `c.foo` is the correct spelling, because `foo` is a global in `c.py`. Are you sure you are testing yoru code correctly?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] for us that demonstrates your problem?